# Unable to get message_ID for MimeMessage

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

I have a java program using `Java Mail-1.`5 that fetch and process message(email) of Gmail(IMAP).
It works fine for most of the case, but for few messages when I try to get message_id using MimeMessage, it is giving me NULL. In that case I am not able to process the messages as messageID is unique for the messages.

> String messageID = ((MimeMessage) msg).getMessageID(); //NULL for few messages.

Is there any other way to get message Id as I don't want to ignore such messages.

Answer (score 3):

Messages are not required to have a Message-Id header.  Most messages do.  And in many cases, if a server receives a message without a Message-Id header, it will add one.  Still, there are no guarantees.  If you're depending on the Message-Id to uniquely identify a message, you need to have a fallback technique for the cases where the message doesn't have a Message-Id.

Answer (score 3):

Use this to force JavaMail API to refresh the headers from the content.

```
((MimeMessage) msg).saveChanges();
```

It should populate the Message-ID header value. The following example is a simple way to generate message IDs at will:

```
MimeMessage mimemessage 
            =new MimeMessage(Session.getDefaultInstance( new Properties()));
mimemessage.saveChanges();
String messageID = mimemessage.getMessageID();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String messageID = ((MimeMessage) msg).getMessageID();
```

Returns `null` if this field is *unavailable* or its value is *absent*.

You can create your *own message id* if it is `null`

```
StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();
if(messageId == null)
messageId =  s.append(s.hashCode()).append('.').append(getUniqueId()).append('.').
append(System.currentTimeMillis()).append('.').
append("JavaMail");
```

This is how message id is created and set when a mail is being sent. You can go with your own implementation based on your requirement and then proceed to process your message